# Printing the words matched by a regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

Ok, I'm going a simple Perl 5 Script that prints out words that begin with D and end with E...

```
$_ = "Dog Die Do Dome";
/^d.*e$/i;
```

As shown, I used Regular Expressions to search through my text to find such words, but how to I print them out? Thank in advance for any help.

Comment: Remember to use a title that will be useful to future visitors to the site. Otherwise the question may be closed as "too localized".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can capture to an array, using the `/g` modifier.

```
use feature 'say';
my @words = /\bd\S+e\b/ig;
say for @words;
```

In list context, this will return all matches which start with a "d" and ends with an "e". Note that you cannot use `.*` because that match is greedy, so `"dog do die"` will return the entire string `dog do die` with a greedy match, and not just `"die"`. Using the word boundary `\b` will prevent you from matching partially, such as with `foobaresk`.

Answer (score 2):

First thing is that your regular expression is capturing your entire string. Regular expressions are *normally* greedy, so the `.*` will match the longest part of the string that's true. Since your regular expression begins with a `d` and ends with an `e`, it will match your whole string.

There are several ways you could avoid this:

```
my $string = "Dog Die Do Dome";
my $string =~ /d[\S]+e/ig;
```

Since `\S` says *no white space*, you are only matching the words that begin with a `D` and end with an `E` and contain no white space. Thus, it will now match `Die` and `Dome`separately, but not `Dog` and `Do`. This is a common trick in regular expressions. For example, you have a string `foo-bar-bam`, and only want to match the first word. Using `/[^-][^-]*/` will do the trick (remember that `*` can stand for ***zero*** or more of the preceding. Thus, you double it up to match at least one.). This is mainly used in older versions of *grep* or *sed* where you don't have the power of Perl's expanded regualar expressions. In my example above, I used `+` instead of `*` because `+` means match ***one*** or more of the preceding.

Perl also has a way to make a Regular expression non-greedy by using appending a question mark after the `*` or `+`:

```
my $string =~ /d.+?e/ig;
```

However, in your case, this would match `Dog Die` and `Dome` which is probably not what you want.

Here's the program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my $string = "Dog Die Do Dome";

my @matches = ($string =~ /D\S+e/gi);

for my $word (@matches) {
    say "The first match is $word";
}
```

And, it prints out:

```
 The first match is Die
 The first match is Dome
```

Okay, maybe I shouldn't use `The first match`, but you get the idea. Try this sample program with various regular expressions and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use the `print` Statement

You use the [print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) statement to send output to the screen. Since you are matching entire lines, you don't have to do anything complex here; you can just use the implied *$_* variable. For example:

```
print if /^d.*e$/i
```

Comment: I think the objective was to print the individual words, not printing the entire string.

Comment: Thanks! This was nice and short, fixed my problem quickly. But where can I place a newline (\n)?

Comment: @sharksfan98 So when you said "printing the words", you actually meant "printing the entire line"?

Comment: @sharksfan98 Add another print statement, or `print "$&\n"` instead of the implied $_.

Comment: No, print out the words of that statement that begin with D and end with E @TLP

Comment: Well then... why did you say this answer fixed your problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
>cat temp
Dog Die Do Dome
>perl -lne '@a=split" ";foreach(@a){print if(/^[dD].*[eE]$/)}' temp
Die
Dome
```

Comment: Or use autosplit `-a` switch and ignore case `/i` modifier with a postscript for loop: `perl -lane'/^d.*e$/i && print for @F' temp`

Answer (score 0):

```
  1 
  2 my $word_list = "Dog Die Do Dome";
  3 my @words = split ' ', $word_list;
  4 for my $word (@words) {
  5         print "$word\n" if $word =~ /^d.*e$/i;
  6     }
~
```

~
~
~

Comment: Otherwise, great answer! Thanks!